# How to debug an HIP/HIPRT application on windows?

Tags: debugging, amd-processor, hip

I'm writing a path tracer using HIPRT on Windows but I couldn't find anything to debug my application yet. I'd like to be able to execute my kernels line by line, watch kernel variables, print to console, ... Those are features available in CUDA with the Nsight extension of Visual Studio.

There is supposedly a Visual Studio extension but I couldn't find any way to install it. [This](https://rocm.docs.amd.com/projects/hip-vs/en/latest/building.html) ROCm tutorial explains how to build the extension yourself but every link to the Visual Studio project used to build the extension is a dead link.

The Windows [HIP SDK installer](https://www.amd.com/en/developer/resources/rocm-hub/eula/licenses.html?filename=AMD-Software-PRO-Edition-23.Q4-Win10-Win11-For-HIP.exe) provides an option to install the extension to Visual Studio for you but ticking the checkbox always results in an error during the installation (it seems [I'm not the only one](https://github.com/ROCm/ROCm/issues/2363)). The only way I can complete the installtion of the SDK is by not installing the HIP extension to Visual Studio.

Unless there is another way to get the HIP extension to work in VS, what tools are there to debug my code on Windows?

Comment: Hi, I think you can report the issue to the product issue page directly, since the hip/hiprt app also generate by it?

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT Done. Here is the github issue for reference: https://github.com/ROCm/HIP/issues/3420